# Start Activity on background

Tags: java, android

I have an app that responds to Internet message by creating a new Activity and user has 20 seconds to respond.

The problem is when the app is running on background.
I can show a notification, but when the  user returns to the App the new Activity isn't started.

Is there any way to start an Activity even when the App isn't on foreground (without the activity getting focus) or any easy workaround where the activity would start right after returning to the app? (which would be worse solution, cause I would have to rework the sync timer :))
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Activity life cycle [image: Android Activity Lifecycle]

Here you have the `onResume()` method you can override and do something before the `Activity` itself is shown. From there you could do some kind of check that you are returning from a notification or a check on that the user has to answer something now and launch a new `Activity` from the `onResume()` method.

Comment: My problem is, that there is Activity A, Activity B and Activity C
Activity A handles the events and opens activity B on event
but also there is a button to open activity C.


How do I know that onResume for A is because of return from background and not because of return from C?

(The activity B starts even if the event triggers during activity C being displayed)